# How to auto detect interface that connected to the internet

Tags: batch-file, tshark

So i have remote machine with simple `.bat` file:

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe -i 1 -w c:\file.pcap
```

This `command` start `Tshark` process and start sniffing

Now my problem is that i start this `.bat` file in several machines and in each machine the correct interface is different so with the commend `Tshaek -D` i can get all the interfaces with the index numbers but from here i need to know which interface is the one the connected to the internet.

And of course i need to do that inside my`.bat` file and this need to be my interface number (in my example the interface number is hard code and equal to 1)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is very hacky, but should do.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^|findstr "IPv4"') do (
    ping -n 1 -S%%i google.com |findstr /i reply
    if not errorlevel 1 for /f %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /I /N "%%i"') do set cnt=%%a
)
set /a cnt-=5
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^|more +%cnt%') do set adap=%%i & goto runts
:runts
set adap=%adap:*adapter =%
for /f "usebackq delims=." %%i in (`""C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -D | findstr /I "%adap%""`) do (
    "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i %%i -w c:\file.pcap
)
```

What we do is, run `ipconfig` and get all `IPv4` addresses and use each as source to ping `google.com`. Using `findstr` we then match `reply` and then `errorlevel 0` will determine whether the adapter was the active one.

Now we simply go up 5 lines to get the description of the adapter, then we `findstr` that adapter using `tshark -D` and simply run the full `tshark` command.

Note, this will be completely different if you use IPv6.